# Android NDK jni problem

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have started teaching myself about the Android NDK and I have followed this example here - http://marakana.com/forums/android/android_examples/49.html

I have followed the steps perfectly but when I run the application I get the following error:

```
Trying to load lib /data/data/com.cnetworks.ndk/lib/libndk_demo.so 0x435c2d20
Added shared lib /data/data/com.cnetworks.ndk/lib/libndk_demo.so 0x435c2d20
No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.cnetworks.ndk/lib/libndk_demo.so 0x435c2d20
+++ not scanning '/system/lib/libwebcore.so' for 'hello' (wrong CL)
+++ not scanning '/system/lib/libmedia_jni.so' for 'hello' (wrong CL)
WARN/dalvikvm(5191): No implementation found for native Lcom/cnetworks/ndk/NativeLib;.hello ()Ljava/lang/String;
```

---

Here is the java code, nativeLib.hello() is causing the problem.

```
public class NDKdemo2 extends Activity {
NativeLib nativeLib;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.main);

 nativeLib = new NativeLib();
 String helloText = nativeLib.hello();

 // Update the UI
 TextView outText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textOut);
 outText.setText(helloText);


 }
}
```

Has anyone had the same problem before and able to tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Can you also include the declaration line of the native function?  The VM is not finding the native method, which often happens if you have a typo in the name or neglected to declare it with 'extern "C"'.  Does the function live in the libndk_demo.so library?

Comment: Thanks, fadden I got it fixed

Comment: Hello Donal, can you tell me how did u solve the above error?

Comment: Donal, could you tell us how you fixed it?

Comment: Donal, it's helpful to tell others how you fixed your problem. Then others can benefit from your knowledge, in the same way you might benefit from theirs by asking questions on this site.

Comment: I believe I was missing the loading function/method in my main JNI linker class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well from my experience there is problem with #define #define **attribute**(x) defined in some file.
Just uncomment the same and then ndk compiled lib will be loaded.